# a specific OpenCL kernel performs differently on mobile and PC

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencl

I was trying to run an OpenCL kernel on both Adreno 630 and my laptop, it turns out that the kernel runs perfectly on mobile but crashes my laptop every single time. I am still trying to figure out the reason by myself. Here's my kernel. I hope you could help me with it, thanks.

```
__kernel void gen_mapxy( __read_only image2d_t _disp, const float offsetX, __write_only image2d_t _mapxy )
{
    const int y = get_global_id(0);

    const int local_y = get_local_id(0);
    __local short temp[24][1080];

    const int imageWidth = get_image_width(_disp);
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x)
        temp[local_y][x] = 0;
    for(int x = imageWidth - 1; x >= 0; --x){
        int tempDisp = read_imagei(_disp, sampler_nearest, (int2)(x, y)).x;
        int newPos = clamp((int)(x + offsetX * (tempDisp) / 255), 0, imageWidth - 1);
        temp[local_y][newPos] = tempDisp;
        write_imagef(_mapxy, (int2)(newPos, y), (float4)(x, y, 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: maybe your inputs are not well set in your pc code. Check that your inputs are indeed correct and have the correct dimensions. Is it the case that you may use different input images/data on mobile than on pc? maybe this is the cause

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` for the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a big local array.

```
__local short temp[24][1080]
```

2 byte * 24 * 1080 = 50.6kB. Some desktop GPUs(and their notebook counterparts) have less available local memory limits. For example, GTX 1060 supports the value `CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE` 49152 bytes. But adreno 620, either it is ignoring the array usage silently or supporting larger local arrays because there is a possilibity that local arrays are emulated inside global arrays (limited in hundreds of megabytes) for those chips. If they do support in-chip fast local memory, then there is more possibility of "ignoring" issue or they really doubled local memory limits from last generation of Adrenos.

Even when GPU supports exact value, using all of it will limit thread-level-parallelism on each pipeline, severely reducing potential performance gains, generally.

If last generation of Adreno GPUs are same,

https://compubench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=compu15m&os=Android&api=cs&D=Samsung+Galaxy+S7+%28SM-G930x%29&testgroup=info

this page says

```
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE
32768

CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE
CL_LOCAL
```

it is fast but it is 32kB so it is ignoring the error or you've missed adding necessary error catching logic in there, or both.

Comment: Yes I agree with that, maybe there's some different configuration between pc and mobile. But In fact on mobile I always get the right output when row size is smaller than 24, when I tried to continue to augment it(32 for example), there will also be crashes on mobile every time. It's still weired.

Comment: Sometimes drivers cause weird issues on OpenCL. Probably mobile SoC GPU vendors not giving enough attention to it, as AMD, NVIDIA, INTEL does.